# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory changes after running test?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest, appdomain

In VS2012, I have a bunch of (MS) unit tests, which use different xml/text files I've stored in the same folder as the test file class.

I open these files using File.OpenRead(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "file")

If I run just one test, it works, the file is read.

If I run all the tests at once, the BaseDirectory returns a different path (in TestResults/Deploy/currentdatetime/Out) and obviously cannot find the file there.

What to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Try [\[DeploymentItem(@"your relative file path")\]][1] attribute for each test.
Also I think you need to add all your files to the project and set their properties to CopyToOutputDirectory set to "CopyAlways".    


http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx

Comment: 1. didn't work :( 2. Already did that, they are copied, the path of basedirectory changes when running multiple tests at once.

Comment: What did you decorate with DeploymentItem attrubute? Test Class or Test Method?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.  I have my .config files in different files.  Example   <MySectionName configSource="MySectionName.SeparateFile.config" />      .   I have "Copy Always" on the MySectionName.SeparateFile.config file.  If I run the test(s) one at a time, everything is fine.  I click "Run All" in "Test Explorer" and I get a ConfigurationErrorsException exception, because it is looking for 'MySectionName.SeparateFile.config' file in the "TestResults/Deploy/currentdatetime/Out" directory.  Boooooooooo!  :(

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue with VS 2017, but all tests including individual tests were being ran from the TestResults folder.  Our problem was with log4net.config not getting copied to the TestResults folder (even though Copy Always was true).

Our solution was to delete the LocalTestRun.testrunconfig file from the Solution Items folder (directly under the solution).  When we did that it started using the \bin\debug\ folder as it should and found our log4net.config file.

Answer (score -1):

Well didn't make it work, and seems like google thinks its never going to.

Workaround was simply to edit the path like:

```
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context)
    {
        string deployDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string[] rows = deployDir.Split(new string[] { "TestResults" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string projectPath = rows[0].ToString();
        _path = projectPath + "newpath\\";
    }
```